# rspec association has error: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I'm having an issue with a factory that is using associations.  I had it working for awhile but had to backup to some lower versions of various gems and cannot get it working anymore.

The error I get is the following:

```
Failures:

  1) PoolMembership 
     Failure/Error: let(:season) { FactoryGirl.create(:season_with_weeks) }
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

And the backtrace shows the following line from my factories.rb as the problem:

```
  transient do
    **number_of_weeks  1**
  end
```

I double checked the FactoryGirl documentation and it looks like I'm doing exactly what the documentation states.  So, I'm assuming I've got a configuration error of some kind or I'm trying to do something with the wrong version of one the gems.

Here is my **factories.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define  do
  factory :week do
    state        0
    week_number  1
    season
  end

  factory :season do  
    year             "2015"
    state            0
    nfl_league       1
    current_week     1
    number_of_weeks  1
    factory :season_with_weeks do

      transient do
        num_weeks  1
      end

      after(:create) do |season, evaluator|
        create_list(:week, evaluator.num_weeks, season: season)
        season.number_of_weeks = evaluator.num_weeks
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And here is the rspec file that I'm using to test it out.
**spec/models/pool_membership_spec.rb:**

```
describe PoolMembership do
  let(:season) { FactoryGirl.create(:season_with_weeks) }

  ...

end
```

And since I think this might be a configuration or version level issue, here are my Gemfile, spec/rails_helper.rb, and spec_helper.rb files.

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org' 
ruby '2.0.0'
#ruby-gemset=Rails_fb

gem 'rails','4.1.1'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.2'
gem 'annotate'
gem 'faker', '1.1.2'
gem 'select2-rails'
gem 'simple_form', '3.1.1'
gem 'cocoon'

#
# Bootstrap support gems
#
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.9'
gem 'font-awesome-sass', '4.1.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.2'
#gem 'select2-sass-bootstrap-rails'

# Database.  Using the same database for production/development
gem 'pg'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~>3.0'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '~> 4.2'
  gem 'spork-rails'
  gem 'guard-spork'
  gem 'childprocess', '0.3.6'
  gem 'letter_opener_web', '~>1.2.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.2.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.1'
  gem 'libnotify', '0.8.0'
end

gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.2.1'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks', '2.0.1'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'

gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
```

**spec/rails_helper.rb**

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate     rspec:install'
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
# Prevent database truncation if the environment is production
abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if     Rails.env.production?
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rspec/rails'
# Add additional requires below this line. Rails is not loaded until this point!

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc, in
# spec/support/ and its subdirectories. Files matching `spec/**/*_spec.rb` are
# run as spec files by default. This means that files in spec/support that end
# in _spec.rb will both be required and run as specs, causing the specs to be
# run twice. It is recommended that you do not name files matching this glob to
# end with _spec.rb. You can configure this pattern with the --pattern
# option on the command line or in ~/.rspec, .rspec or `.rspec-local`.
#
# The following line is provided for convenience purposes. It has the downside
# of increasing the boot-up time by auto-requiring all files in the support
# directory. Alternatively, in the individual `*_spec.rb` files, manually
# require only the support files necessary.
#
# Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }

# Checks for pending migrations before tests are run.
# If you are not using ActiveRecord, you can remove this line.
ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  # RSpec Rails can automatically mix in different behaviours to your tests
  # based on their file location, for example enabling you to call `get` and
  # `post` in specs under `spec/controllers`.
  #
  # You can disable this behaviour by removing the line below, and instead
  # explicitly tag your specs with their type, e.g.:
  #
  #     RSpec.describe UsersController, :type => :controller do
  #       # ...
  #     end
  #
  # The different available types are documented in the features, such as in
  # https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
end
```

and **spec/spec_helper.rb**

```
# This file was generated by the `rails generate rspec:install` command. Conventionally, all
# specs live under a `spec` directory, which RSpec adds to the `$LOAD_PATH`.
# The generated `.rspec` file contains `--require spec_helper` which will cause
# this file to always be loaded, without a need to explicitly require it in any
# files.
#
# Given that it is always loaded, you are encouraged to keep this file as
# light-weight as possible. Requiring heavyweight dependencies from this file
# will add to the boot time of your test suite on EVERY test run, even for an
# individual file that may not need all of that loaded. Instead, consider making
# a separate helper file that requires the additional dependencies and performs
# the additional setup, and require it from the spec files that actually need
# it.
#
# The `.rspec` file also contains a few flags that are not defaults but that
# users commonly want.
#
# See http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Configuration
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # rspec-expectations config goes here. You can use an alternate
  # assertion/expectation library such as wrong or the stdlib/minitest
  # assertions if you prefer.
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    # This option will default to `true` in RSpec 4. It makes the `description`
    # and `failure_message` of custom matchers include text for helper methods
    # defined using `chain`, e.g.:
    #     be_bigger_than(2).and_smaller_than(4).description
    #     # => "be bigger than 2 and smaller than 4"
    # ...rather than:
    #     # => "be bigger than 2"
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  # rspec-mocks config goes here. You can use an alternate test double
  # library (such as bogus or mocha) by changing the `mock_with` option here.
  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    # Prevents you from mocking or stubbing a method that does not exist on
    # a real object. This is generally recommended, and will default to
    # `true` in RSpec 4.
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end

# The settings below are suggested to provide a good initial experience
# with RSpec, but feel free to customize to your heart's content.
=begin
  # These two settings work together to allow you to limit a spec run
  # to individual examples or groups you care about by tagging them with
  # `:focus` metadata. When nothing is tagged with `:focus`, all examples
  # get run.
  config.filter_run :focus
  config.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true

  # Allows RSpec to persist some state between runs in order to support
  # the `--only-failures` and `--next-failure` CLI options. We recommend
  # you configure your source control system to ignore this file.
  config.example_status_persistence_file_path = "spec/examples.txt"

  # Limits the available syntax to the non-monkey patched syntax that is
  # recommended. For more details, see:
  #   - http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax
  #   - http://www.teaisaweso.me/blog/2013/05/27/rspecs-new-message-expectation-syntax/
  #   - http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2014/05/notable-changes-in-rspec-3#new__config_option_to_disable_rspeccore_monkey_patching
  config.disable_monkey_patching!

  # Many RSpec users commonly either run the entire suite or an individual
  # file, and it's useful to allow more verbose output when running an
  # individual spec file.
  if config.files_to_run.one?
    # Use the documentation formatter for detailed output,
    # unless a formatter has already been configured
    # (e.g. via a command-line flag).
    config.default_formatter = 'doc'
  end

  # Print the 10 slowest examples and example groups at the
  # end of the spec run, to help surface which specs are running
  # particularly slow.
  config.profile_examples = 10

  # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
  # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
  # the seed, which is printed after each run.
  #     --seed 1234
  config.order = :random

  # Seed global randomization in this process using the `--seed` CLI option.
  # Setting this allows you to use `--seed` to deterministically reproduce
  # test failures related to randomization by passing the same `--seed` value
  # as the one that triggered the failure.
  Kernel.srand config.seed
=end
end
```

Comment: I'd suggest turning backtrace on in RSpec to see what code (within the invocation of the factory) is failing. My guess is that it's during the `create_list` call.

Comment: The problem it has is with the line   'transient do      ** number_of_weeks  1 **     end' I'm not sure why that transient variable  is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this answer in another problem.  Apparently, I was reading the documentation for version 5.0 of FactoryGirl but using version 4.4.0 which doesn't support transient, it uses ignore instead. So, just needed to change from transient to ignore.

was:

```
transient do
  num_weeks  1
end
```

Changed to:

```
  ignore do
    num_weeks  1
  end
```

Comment: Was it `num_weeks` or `number_or_weeks`? Your question includes both.

Comment: Traced it down to 5.0 vs. 4.4.0 and then saw you already updated your answer. Glad you figured it out. :-)